# Xammp vs webserver - file paths

Tags: php, path, xampp, google-visualization, data-import

Probably, this is another noob question, but I really do not get along on my own:

I developed a website, where a chart shall be included, using the google-chart-tool. Therefore, a php-file is embedded in the HTML, which opens a json-file containing the chart data. Under xammp on my home machine everything works fine, but on the webserver it does not. 
The php lives in the same folder like the HTML, the json is in another folder. I thought maybe this is a path problem and tried with absolute paths on the webserver, but that does not change the situation. 
Maybe the paths are not the problem? Does anybody have an idea on this?
Thanks in advance!

Sadly, I can not give you a url  or anything, since the site will be "partly business" and my boss is kind of a secret keeper ;-)
I will add the link when its done, though...

Comment: How is it embedded? Iframe? Ajax? or something else?

Comment: Javascript > Ajax     I just followed the documentation on the google charts; but I don't really know Ajax...

Comment: do you have firebug installed on your browser? Can you see the request? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. The firebug shows the div containinig the chart, but nothing is to be seen. When using "inspect", I am not able to select the area where the chart should appear.

Comment: No I meant do you see the ajax request in the Console? Do you get a 200 Response or an error?

Comment: What initiates the ajax request?

Comment: Well, I did not use any console; the code for loading ajax looks like this: `<!--Load the AJAX API-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com /jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});`

Comment: No I meant the console tab in Firebug, you should be able to see the ajax request. If not, whatever is suppose to trigger the ajax isn't firing.

Comment: ah, thanks! I get two errors: 404 and 500 .... Fixed the 404, that really was a path issue. But with the 500 it stil.l does not work

Comment: 500 error means you have a problem in the php. Check your error log on the server.